# Sql error ERROR 1064 (42000): while creating a simple table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying these commands in my MySQL server terminal:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS XDB;

USE XDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XDB.User (id UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL, emailid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE(emailid));
```

but it is providing me with error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL, emailid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, status VARCHAR(255) NOT NU' at line 1

Comment: The error almost makes it look like your command is being cutoff halfway.

Comment: "INT UNSIGNED" order matters.

Answer (score 1):

'INT' is a type, 'UNSIGNED' is a numberici type attribute.

So 'INT' must come before 'UNSIGNED' in the syntax.

Comment: catches me often as I switch between C and SQL too :-)

Comment: Shouldn't you be voting to close this as a typo question?